# MVC Html.TextArea overload issue

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form in an MVC view which contains a number of text boxes, drop down lists and text areas. I am using the HTML helper to create these controls, including pre-populating them with View Data where appropriate, and applying styles via the htmlAttributes parameter.

This is working fine with TextBox controls and DropDownLists etc, however when I add the htmlAttributes to the TextArea it stops working, claiming that the best overloaded method has some invalid arguments, the code that is failing is:

```
Html.TextArea("Description", ViewData["Description_Current"], new { @class = "DataEntryStd_TextArea" })
```

The resulting error is:

> 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TextArea'
>   and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.Html.TextAreaExtensions.TextArea(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,
>   string, string, object)' has some invalid arguments

For comparison the TextBox calls that are working fine are:

```
Html.TextBox("TelephoneNumberAlternate", ViewData["TelephoneNumberAlternate"], new { @class = "DataEntryStd_TextBox" })
```

I tried explicitly referencing the TextAreaExtensions.TextArea and including the HtmlHelper argument however this made no difference.

For info the TextArea call works fine without the htmlAttributes parameter. Additionally I have tried specifying a name/value dictionary for the class attribute however this suffers the exact same problem.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Awesome work guys. Got to love the fact that the SO community are so fast that issues I can't solve alone don't particularly impact on my day! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It always bugs me that these error messages don't tell you *which one* of the arguments don't match.

Have you tried this?

```
Html.TextArea("Description", ViewData["Description_Current"].ToString(), new { @class = "DataEntryStd_TextArea" })
```

The reason I ask is that the `ViewData["Description_Current"]` is of type `Object`, and there is an overload with the signature `Html.TextArea(String, Object)` - although the object in this case represents the html attributes. That could be why the compiler doesn't complain until you add the html attributes as a third parameter - until then, the second parameter is allowed to be an `Object`, but as soon as you add the third parameter the second has to be a `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the ViewData["Description_Current"] to string as the method requires the signature (string, string, object) not (string, object, object).  The TextBox works because there is a signature using html attributes that takes (string, object, object).

```
<%= Html.TextArea( "Name",
                   (string)ViewData["Value"],
                   new { @class = "klass" } ) %>
```

Docs for [HtmlHelper.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textbox.aspx) and [HtmlHelper.TextArea](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.textareaextensions.aspx) are available at MSDN.